# Printing global structure of a Matlab script

Tags: matlab, extract

I have a large Matlab script and I would like to extract only lines that contain `for`, `while`, `if`, `end`, etc. The indentation should be included. For instance:

```
%original
for i=1:2 %display text
    disp('I like you')
    if j==k % check if j=k
        disp('very much')
    end
end

%result
for i=1:2 %display text
    if j==k % check if j=k
    end
end
```

I want to use this overview to have a better overview of the structure of the code. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
f = fopen('myfile.m', 'rt');
a = textscan(f, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'Whitespace', '');
    fclose(f);

p = @(x) ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(a{1},x));
b = a{1}(p('for') | p('while') | p('if') | p('end'));
```

Please note that `strfind` is quite straightforward (to be read: dumb) in identifying sub-strings in a line; if you need more refined search (e.g. whole words only) you'd be safer using `regexp`.

Comment: Nice! How can I include the original indentation? (I edited the question.)

Comment: Some refinement could be done, depending on the exact goal of the user. For instance, variable names containing 'if' are also preserved.

Comment: @MWc That's why I pointed out that instead of `strfind` one might want to use `regexp` which has more refined control over the matched content.